# Simple Discount

Tags: java, discount

Studying for an exam and have a problem,I am a beginner.
Its a discount calculator. 
Bag of coffee costs €3.75
10 bags or more 5% discount
20 bags or more 10% discount

What I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class discount {
public static void main (String[] args){

//Scanner input; Keep this as one line. It is good practice
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double bag;
double discount;
double cost = 3.75;

//Input = new Scanner(System.ini);     combined with line above.
System.out.println("Enter Numer of bag");
bag = input.nextDouble();
//If (bag ==>10&&<20) × .05  incorrect Java syntax

if(bag >= 10 && < 20) {
 discount = 0.05;
}
else if(bag >= 20) {
  discount = 0.10;
} 
else {
  discount = 0;
}

double finalPrice;
finalPrice = (cost * bag) * (1 - discount);

System.out.println("You ordered " + bag + " bags of coffee.");
System.out.println("Your dicount is " + discount + "%");
System.out.println("You total is: " + finalPrice);
```

}
}

Comment: I'd suggest you brush up on basic Java syntax, pronto.

Comment: This is not valid Java.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? You are missing a LOT of basic syntax in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if(bag >= 10 && < 20)

to

> if(bag >= 10 && **bag** < 20)

An easy mistake for a beginner!
I kinda agree with the lecturer re the editor vs ide while learning the basics.  You need to learn to read what the compiler tells you is wrong. And once you know the problem, I think you will agree, the syntax error message above gives a good indication of what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually not in favor of doing assignments for Tom Sawyer students, but in this case I think there's educational opportunity for any beginner who learns to look at the problem differently.

This is a simple class, but it's a good idea to develop good habits if you want to be a programmer.

Pay a lot of attention to code formatting and readability.    Think long and hard about names for classes, methods, and variables.  You need fewer comments if the names are self-explanatory.

Learn and follow [Java coding standards](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).  That will help readability.

Forget about input and output and the user interface - get the functionality right first.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * CoffeePriceCalculator
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 7/22/2016
 * Time: 7:46 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525213/simple-discount
 */
public class CoffeePriceCalculator {

    // Is double a good way to represent money?  What about units?  Conversions?
    public static final double DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE = 3.75;  // British pounds

    private static final Map<Integer, Double> DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE;

    static {
        DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE.put(10, 0.05);
        DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE.put(20, 0.10);
    }

    public double calculatePrice(int numBags, double unitPrice) {
        if (numBags < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of bags must be positive");
        if (unitPrice < 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unit price must be positive");
        double price = numBags*unitPrice;
        price -= calculateDiscount(numBags, price);
        return price;
    }

    public double calculatePrice(int numBags) {
        return this.calculatePrice(numBags, DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE);
    }

    public double calculateDiscount(int numBags, double price) {
        if (numBags < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of bags must be positive");
        if (price < 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Total price must be positive");
        double discount = 0.0;
        for (int minBags : DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE.keySet()) {
            if (numBags >= minBags) {
                discount = price*DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE.get(minBags);
                break;
            }
        }
        return discount;
    }
}
```

It's not too early to learn about [JUnit](http://www.junit.org) and Test Driven Development.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Junit test for CoffeePriceCalculator
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 7/22/2016
 * Time: 7:50 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525213/simple-discount
 */
public class CoffeePriceCalculatorTest {

    public static final double TOLERANCE = 1.0e-3;

    @Test
    public void testCalculatePrice_NoDiscount() {
        // setup
        CoffeePriceCalculator coffeePriceCalculator = new CoffeePriceCalculator();
        int numBags = 5;
        // exercise
        double actual = coffeePriceCalculator.calculatePrice(numBags);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(numBags * CoffeePriceCalculator.DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE, actual, TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculatorPrice_LowDiscount() {
        // setup
        CoffeePriceCalculator coffeePriceCalculator = new CoffeePriceCalculator();
        int numBags = 15;
        // exercise
        double actual = coffeePriceCalculator.calculatePrice(numBags);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(numBags * CoffeePriceCalculator.DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE*0.95, actual, TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculatorPrice_HighDiscount() {
        // setup
        CoffeePriceCalculator coffeePriceCalculator = new CoffeePriceCalculator();
        int numBags = 25;
        // exercise
        double actual = coffeePriceCalculator.calculatePrice(numBags);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(numBags * CoffeePriceCalculator.DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE*0.90, actual, TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testCalculatePrice_NegativeBags() {
        // setup
        CoffeePriceCalculator coffeePriceCalculator = new CoffeePriceCalculator();
        int numBags = -25;
        // exercise
        coffeePriceCalculator.calculatePrice(numBags);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your exam is not coming up too soon, because you have a lot of syntax to review.

I don't really like giving straight up answers to homework questions, so I will fix up what you currently have, and perhaps that will point you in the right direction.

```
Import.java.util.scanner;

public class discount {
  public static void main (String[] args){

    //Scanner input; Keep this as one line. It is good practice
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Float bag;
   int bag;
    Float discount;
    Double cost = 3.75;

    //Input = new Scanner(System.ini);     combined with line above.
    System.out.println("Enter Numer of bag");
    bag = input.nextFloat();
    //If (bag ==>10&&<20) × .05  incorrect Java syntax

    //if(bag >= 10 && < 20) {
    if(bag >= 10 && bag < 20) {
     discount = 0.05;
    }
    else if(bag >= 20) {
      discount = 0.10;
    } 
    else {
      //discount = 0;
      discount = 0.0;
    }

    double finalPrice;
    finalPrice = (cost * bag) * (1 - discount);

    //System.out.println("You ordered " + bag + " bags of coffee.);
    System.out.println("You ordered " + bag + " bags of coffee.");
    System.out.println("Your dicount is " + discount + "%");
    System.out.println("Your total is: " + finalPrice);
  }
}
```

Remember to keep your code clean so you do not confuse yourself. Make sure you indent your code.

Think about what you are naming your variables, and do not be afraid to refactor them if you come up with something better. Using clear and logical naming will reduce the number of comments you will need to write.

And as I mentioned before, study up on your syntax. There were a lot of syntax errors in your code, which leads me to believe that maybe you are writing your code in notepad or from the command line? If so I would recommend using an IDE such as IntelliJ, NetBeans, or Eclipse. These will underline your syntax errors and point out mistakes that you may not notice straight away.

Comment: Thanks,my exam is not till end of Auguest,I wasnt using an ide.I am now.My lecture told me to use a notepad first and was doing it that way.

Comment: This is the only error I get now?            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int
 Syntax error on token "<", delete this token

Comment: See edited code for more changes. I would also like to point out that your line `System.out.println("Your dicount is " + discount + "%");` is not correct. Your customer gets a 5% discount, but this line is telling him that he got a 0.05% discount.